# Will the current able to flow or capacitor able to work in this circuit?

Tags: capacitor, current, inductor, short-circuit

[image]

If the switch is closed, how does the capacitor work in this condition?  I know that the main source is shorted. How about the capacitor? Will there be current flowing from the capacitor through the shorted wire?

Answer (score 3):

> how is capacitor work in this condition?

The voltage on the capacitor will oscillate and decrease rapidly over time. So will the current, but out of phase with the voltage.

> I know that the main source is shorted."

No, it is not: there's a 10 Ohm resistor in there.

> How about capacitor?

No, it is not: there's a 30 Ohm resistor in there.

> Will there be flow from capacitor through shorted wire?

Yes, for a while, until all the energy in the capacitor is dissipated.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply, just to check,so there would be 2 flows in the shorted wire? one from sources and another from capacitor?

Comment: Yes, correct. DC from the source, AC from the capacitor.

Comment: Thank You! @Davide Andrea